# put focus on an EditorFor MVC 5

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

An attempt is made to place the focus in an EditorFor within a modal window

[image: Screenshot]

My View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Kn_CodigoProducto, "Producto", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Kn_CodigoProducto, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus="true",  @required = "true"} })
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried with different ways, even putting Javascript to the Object, but I do not get the desired result, which is basically that when the user opens the modal for the EditorFor this asset (with focus), I am working with the.Net Framework 4.5 in MVC 5, any help for me?

Comment: did you try     $('#Idofelement').focus(); from jquery?

Comment: yes, but I do not get the desired result, will it be because it is inside a modal? I need to add something?
PS: when I start the project from my modal view, if the autofocus works, but it appears in a normal view, not in a partial one obviously @HazarathChillara

Comment: try the answer i gave below. it will search for id of element with in modal window.

Comment: That's most likely because you put the code in the wrong place. You have to add that in the document ready of the partial view

Comment: you say put the script code in the normal view that calls the partial view? @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: No, I said specifically in the document ready of the partial view

Comment: No, putting in code in @section Scripts {
     @ Scripts.Render ("~ / bundles / jqueryval")
<script>
      $ (function () {
          $ ('# editorfocus'). focus ()
        });
</ script>
}

It does not work

Answer (score 0):

Add `Id` for `editor` for e.g.

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Kn_CodigoProducto, "Producto", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Kn_CodigoProducto, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus="true", id="productoId" @required = "true"} })
                 </div>
                </div>
```

and in jquery :

```
$ ('#modalID').find('#productoId').focus();
```

note: replace `#modelID` with actual modal id of your modal.

Comment: Why not just `$('#productoId').focus();`?